# PHP trigger from webpage A to load content from database on webpage B

Tags: php, ajax

I am building a chat and all works fine.

When person A types a message in a textarea and clicks the SEND button of an HTML form, PHP sends it to the server.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // collect textarea content
    // inserted (appended) to mySQL table.
    // collect chat content in mySQL table
    // display chat content in a <div> 
    }
?>
```

(I am not posting the PHP code because it's irrelevant to the problem)

Person B gets the message because of a javascript setInterval that triggers a function that grabs the chat content from the database via AJAX and then displays the chat content for person B in a div.

```
setInterval(refreshChat, 1000);
function refreshChat() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://eyesonpi.com/_/php/chat.php",
        type: "post",
        success: function(data) {
        $("#chatWindow").html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
        $("#chatWindow").prepend("Error");
        }
        });
    }
```

When I tried it on my iPhone, running IOS 10, the AJAX call fails. IOS 10 has a problem with AJAX.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64526

I tried with plain Javascript (xmlHttpRequest) and with jQuery.

I tried the chat window of my hosting company from my iPhone and their chat works. I don't know where to begin with a workaround. How can person B get the message from person A without reloading the page? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: So it works on other devices but not your phone?

Comment: Yup, even older IOS versions. It runs on Android, no problems at all except with IOS 10. There was just an update for IOS 10 and they did not fix it. I hope they won't wait till IOS 11 to do so.

Comment: @Kobbe have you tried with xmlHttpRequest?

Comment: Yes, both with plain javascript and with jQuery.

Comment: Does it take longer than 60 seconds to make that call? That seems to be the issue being talked about in the link you provided.

Comment: I read that too, it's apparently set to a minimum of one minute, but that's way too long for a chat.

Comment: I just thought of setting a Javascript setTimeout for a function that will send the form by using $("#myForm").submit(); It doesn't really matter if the textarea has content or not. It will trigger the PHP and refresh the chat. Been aching my head for two hours and I think this might solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for the chat. Or long pooling technology which allows connection to be persistent between server and client(browser or mobile app).
if you choose websockets. Then you can try to use on server side: 
[Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman) or [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).Both, perfect do their job. All modern browsers natively support websocket, or you can use popular libraries like sockJS for cross-browser support.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I will look into this, but as I just posted in a comment above, I just thought of a Javascript setTimeout for a function that sends the form by using $("#myForm").submit(); It doesn't matter if the textarea has content or not. It will trigger the PHP and refresh the chat. If that is easier and faster than your suggestion, then I guess that will solve it. But will look at your suggestion right now.

Comment: That was a dumb idea :-( as the newly entered text gets sent without clicking the SEND button, leaving no time to type. Alright, onto your suggestion now.

Comment: OK, I just had a quick read and the solution is websockets. Thanks Nurik.

Comment: Maybe your current problem occurs, because you trying to send  xmlHttpRequest to server, that not allows cross-origin resource sharing aka CORS ? Anyway, websockets or long pooling better approach to build chats.

Comment: It works just fine with AJAX except for IOS 10, but I will go for your suggestion. That's probably what some chat services use, like LivePerson, as I was able to get on the chat from my iPhone with my hosting company. Thank you for your time Nurik, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `setInterval` to `setTimeout` behaviour, otherwise previous request will be killed if the next is submitted

```
setTimeout(refreshChat, 0);
function refreshChat() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://eyesonpi.com/_/php/chat.php",
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#chatWindow").html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#chatWindow").prepend("Error");
        }
    }).always(function () {
        setTimeout(refreshChat, 1000);
    });
}
```